# Find the random variable with the greatest expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, random

Let $X$ be a random variable and we want to choose $Y$ such that the following inequality is satisfied
$$\mathbb{E}[XY]\leq 1.$$
We know that for example $Y=1/X$ is a choice. Among all acceptable random variables $Y$, what can we say about the one with the greatest expected value $\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

Comment: Do you have any other information on $X$ or $Y$? Generally, you can't say much about a random variable just by looking at its first moment.

Comment: I agree with @max. I don't think there is a definite solution without additional constraints. Fix $X = \epsilon > 0$ and $Y = 1/\epsilon$ (constant random variables). In this case, $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ can be made arbitrarily large by making $\epsilon$ small enough.